# Working With A Codename One Project In Git/SVN version control

Tags: codenameone

We are trying to work on a Codename One project using git version control.

When I pull the project from git, the files (modified and newly added theme res files) are updated but they don't appear in the theme.

My changes aren't reflected when I try to run the project, how to refresh the project?

I tried to build/clean, refresh the cn1lib too but made no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually triggered by a feature specifically designed for working with a team in version controlled environments. You can get this to work by unchecking `File->XML Team Mode` in the designer but that would "work around" this feature: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/teamwork-and-other-things.html

The solution would be to checkin the `res` directory, when it exists opening the res file refers to that instead of to the theme file. This allows your team to edit that directory together and avoid conflicts that will arise when sharing the binary res file.

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou shai, i uncheck the xml team mode but that doesnt make any difference.. you gave the link (https://www.codenameone.com/team.html), what is this for?? sorry i didn't quite get it. 
And the solution isnt that clear. what do you mean by checking the res directory...
Let me clear my problem here.. when my team member adds a form (eg main form) in the gui builder, it get pulled from git in my project. there r 2 files main.ui and main file but when i open my res file or gui builder, the main form is not there.

Comment: you need to use commands (add comment not add answer). I fixed the link (completion in the browser issue) Make sure all your devs have the Team Mode set to the same value and that the res directory content is committed together with the res file. Opening in the designer should show the changes.