# Which files and folders for version control

Tags: codenameone

This is just a newbie question, but what files and folders should be kept in version control software (we use mercurial, but this isn't the subject)?

I think there are those files and folders:

```
src/
res/
lib/
native/
override/
test/
build.xml
codenameone_settings.properties
icon.png
```

Do you have some other recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list seems to be about right. For reference this is what we use as our `.gitignore` file in our projects:

```
*.jar
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
lib/CodenameOne_SRC.zip
lib/impl/
```

Notice we didn't fully exclude the lib directory only its jars, zip and impl subdirectory. This means that [cn1libs](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) that we include will be under source control which isn't necessarily the best policy (since they are binary) but its convenient.

Also check out [Working With A Codename One Project In Git/SVN version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101797/working-with-a-codename-one-project-in-git-svn-version-control/34101798#34101798)

I cover the specific particulars of working with the resource file and res file hierarchy in version control in that answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I'm looking for!